# Extract specific data from a KML attribute table using R

Tags: r, xml, kml

I am automating a process to download and extract data from a KML from the internet.  The values I am trying to extract are in a large string and I cannot figure out how to get the single needed values out.

```
basins <- c('CARSON - CRSN CITY L (STWN2LLF)',
            'CARSON - CRSN CITY L (STWN2LUF)',
            'EF CARSON - GRDNVL L (GRDN2LLF)',
            'EF CARSON - GRDNVL L (GRDN2LUF)',
            'EF CARSON-MRKLEEVLLE (CEMC1HLF)',
            'EF CARSON-MRKLEEVLLE (CEMC1HUF)',
            'WF CARSON - WOODFRDS (WOOC1HOF)')

date <- c('Mar_04_2023')
url_upper <- paste('https://www.cnrfc.noaa.gov/archive/sweBasins/SWEbasinsVal_', date, ".kml", sep = "")
kml_upper <- st_read(url_upper)
kml_upper <- subset(kml_upper, kml_upper$Name %in% basins)
kml_upper$geometry <- NULL
head(kml_upper,3)
```

The data looks like this:
[image]

I need to extract out the 43.81 in, which comes after the "...Simulated Basin Snow Water Equivalent for Mar 04, 2023".  I am not able to add the specific text, because SO recognizes it as formatting.

What is the best way to extract the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the information you are requesting is stored as a HTML table inside the xml/xml code.  I am sure there is a way for sf to extract out the information.
This is not that way.  I am extracting the HTML out of the XML using the xml2 library.  Then I am convert the text into HTML with rvest to extract the table out into a usable form.

Out of your basin list, I was only able to find 3 in the downloaded file.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
library(xml2)

page <- xml2::read_xml(url_upper)
#xml2::xml_ns(page)
xml_ns_strip(page)  #strip the name space

#find all of the placemarks and extract out
places <- page %>% xml_find_all(".//Placemark")
#get the names 
namesOfPlaces <- places %>% xml_find_first(".//name") %>% xml_text()
#find the places from the names o which are in basin list (3 in this case)
placesOfInterest <- which(namesOfPlaces %in% basins)
descriptionsInPlaces <- places %>% xml_find_all(".//description") %>% xml_text()
#reduce descriptions down to ones of interest
descriptionsInPlaces <- descriptionsInPlaces[placesOfInterest]

#loop through the list extracting the desired information
answer <- lapply(descriptionsInPlaces, function(node){
   convertHTML <- read_html(node)
   output <- convertHTML %>% html_elements("table") %>% html_table()
})
names(answer) <- namesOfPlaces[placesOfInterest]
#a list of table with the requested information
```

Here is the resultant data.  I leave it to the reader to extract the first row for each data frame in the list.

```
    answer
$`EF CARSON-MRKLEEVLLE (CEMC1HUF)`
$`EF CARSON-MRKLEEVLLE (CEMC1HUF)`[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  X1                                                      X2       
  <chr>                                                   <chr>    
1 Simulated Basin Snow Water Equivalent for Mar 04, 2023: 43.81 in.
2 SWE Percent of Normal:                                  207%     
3 Average month-to-date SWE through Mar 04, 2023:         21.12 in.


$`EF CARSON - GRDNVL L (GRDN2LUF)`
$`EF CARSON - GRDNVL L (GRDN2LUF)`[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  X1                                                      X2       
  <chr>                                                   <chr>    
1 Simulated Basin Snow Water Equivalent for Mar 04, 2023: 16.07 in.
2 SWE Percent of Normal:                                  429%     
3 Average month-to-date SWE through Mar 04, 2023:         3.75 in. 


$`CARSON - CRSN CITY L (STWN2LUF)`
$`CARSON - CRSN CITY L (STWN2LUF)`[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  X1                                                      X2       
  <chr>                                                   <chr>    
1 Simulated Basin Snow Water Equivalent for Mar 04, 2023: 15.26 in.
2 SWE Percent of Normal:                                  307%     
3 Average month-to-date SWE through Mar 04, 2023:         4.97 in.
```

Comment: Thank you!  I had no idea that the data was stored in HTML.